# Infinite keyword duplication

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

**What is the bug about:**
Keyword gets duplicated even when the query is not modified.

**Impact:**
As far as i can tell - cosmetic.

**How to replicate:**
Go to: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/python and keep pressing `Search` button. With each search there will be a duplicate python keyword appended to search box.

**Best guess for what is causing it:**
I think you have somewhere a piece of code that appends tag as a keyword without checking if it is already present. My reasoning comes from this url:
https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/?searchTerm=python not having the same issue - the tag is not present in it.

Answer (score 8):

Repro'ed. Your guess sounds right. We'll pop it on the TODO list for Monday morning. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

This should be resolved now, one of our routes was bad.

Comment: Time for retagging then? :-)