# Stackoverflow Careers Search adding same keyword for each search

Tags: discussion, bug, jobs, search

While searching Stackoverflow Careers, it's adding same keyword each time when we do Search. like below.
**While Searching First Time**
[image]
**While Searching Second Time**
[image]

This is raised in this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243280/infinite-keyword-duplication) also, is there any updated on this?